# Usage of "at its zenith"

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, adjective-phrases

Excerpted from [The New Yorker](http://www.newyorker.com/books/page-turner/canon-fodder-denouncing-the-classics):

> Eliot thought that a classic, in the strictest sense, **was a work that apotheosized a great civilization at its zenith**; so exacting (or, if you like, priggish) are his standards that literally the only writer to entirely fulfill them is Virgil.

Literally to me, the bolded sentence means a classic work makes a *already at its peak*(zenith) civilization become better to the god-level.

But if so then it doesn't make sense, it should mean making a *not at its peak* civilization to its peak form, but then the sentence should be "was a work that apotheosized a great civilisation **to** its zenith".

So what's the deal here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author is saying that Eliot's definition of a **classic** piece of work comes from a civilisation **already at its height** (when it could not get any higher) and is written in such a way to make it the civilisation's reputation go **even higher**.

So specific / focused / picky is this definition that only **Virgil** fulfills the requirements.

Answer (score 4):

*Apotheosize* can simply mean to glorify, to idolize, so not necessarily to raise (higher than something's highest height).

[Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/apotheosize?q=Apotheosize)

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/apotheosize)

Comment: I was just going to make much the same point in a comment before I noticed your answer. But thinking about it more carefully, I think you're absolutely right that *this **is** the "correct" answer*. There wouldn't be a question at all if OP weren't assuming that *apotheosizing* somehow inherently "improves" the essential nature of its subject (as opposed to simply elevating its *reputation*).